# On the isomorphism $\mathcal Ext^1(i_*L,\mathcal O_X) \cong \mathcal O_C(C) \otimes L^*$ on a complex algebraic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be smooth irreducible projective curve in a smooth irreducible complex projective surface $X$ (in $\mathbb P^3$) and $L$ be a globally generated line bundle on $C$. Then we have the following isomorphism $\mathcal Ext^1(i_*L,\mathcal O_X) \cong \mathcal Hom(i_*L, i_*i^*\mathcal O_X(C))$, where $i : C \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion.

Then my question is that is the following continuation of it correct?

$$\mathcal Hom(i_*L, i_*i^*\mathcal O_X(C)) \cong i_*(\mathcal Hom(L, i^*\mathcal O_X(C))) \cong i_*(\mathcal Hom(\mathcal O_X, i^*\mathcal O_X(C) \otimes L^*)) \cong i_*(i^*\mathcal O_X(C) \otimes L^*)$$

Then denoting  $i^*\mathcal O_X(C)$ as $\mathcal O_C(C)$ we have $\mathcal Ext^1(i_*L,\mathcal O_X) \cong i_*(\mathcal O_C(C) \otimes L^*)$. Since the pushforward is understood we write it as $\mathcal Ext^1(i_*L,\mathcal O_X) \cong \mathcal O_C(C) \otimes L^*$

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: $L$ is a line bundle on curve? And why is $\mathcal Ext^1(i_*L,\mathcal O_X) \cong \mathcal Hom(i_*L, i_*i^*\mathcal O_X(C))$?

Comment: @AGlearner, thanks for pointing out. Now I have edited the question. The above isomorphism can be seen by dualizing the S.E.S obtained from the canonical evaluation map.